# How to change the schema of a DataFrame (to fix the names of some nested fields)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an issue where when we load a Json file into Spark, store it as Parquet and then try and access the Parquet file from Impala; Impala complains about the names of the columns as they contain characters which are illegal in SQL.

One of the "features" of the JSON files is that they don't have a predefined schema. I want Spark to create the schema, and then I have to modify the field names that have illegal characters.

My first thought was to use `withColumnRenamed` on the names of the fields in the DataFrame but this only works on top level fields I believe, so I could not use that as the Json contains nested data.

So I created the following code to recreate the DataFrames schema, going recursively through the structure.  And then I use that new schema to recreate the DataFrame.

(Code updated with Jacek's suggested improvment of using the Scala copy constructor.)

```
def replaceIllegal(s: String): String = s.replace("-", "_").replace("&", "_").replace("\"", "_").replace("[", "_").replace("[", "_")
def removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(schema: StructType): StructType = {
  StructType(schema.fields.map { field =>
    field.dataType match {
      case struct: StructType =>
        field.copy(name = replaceIllegal(field.name), dataType = removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(struct))
      case _ =>
        field.copy(name = replaceIllegal(field.name))
    }
  })
}

sparkSession.createDataFrame(df.rdd, removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(df.schema))
```

This works.  But is there a better / simpler way to achive what I want to do?

And is there a better way to replace the existing schema on a DataFrame?  The following code did not work:

```
df.select($"*".cast(removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(df.schema)))
```

It gives this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'cast'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best bet would be to convert the Dataset (before you save as a parquet file) to an RDD and use your custom schema to describe the structure as you want.

```
val targetSchema: StructType = ...
val fromJson: DataFrame = ...
val targetDataset = spark.createDataFrame(fromJson.rdd, targetSchema)
```

See the example in [SparkSession.createDataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataFrame(rowRDD:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) as a reference however it uses an RDD directly while you're going to create it from a Dataset.

```
val schema =
  StructType(
    StructField("name", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("age", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)

val people =
  sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(
    _.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
val dataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(people, schema)
dataFrame.printSchema
// root
// |-- name: string (nullable = false)
// |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```

But as you mentioned in your comment (that I later merged to your question):

> JSON files don't have a predefined schema.

With that said, I think your solution is a correct one. Spark does not offer anything similar out of the box and I think it's more about developing a custom Scala code that would traverse a `StructType`/`StructField` tree and change what's incorrect.

What I would suggest to change in your code is to use the `copy` constructor (a feature of Scala's case classes - see [A Scala case class ‘copy’ method example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-case-class-copy-method-example)) that would only change the incorrect name with the other properties untouched.

Using `copy` constructor would (roughly) correspond to the following code:

```
// was
// case s: StructType =>
//    StructField(replaceIllegal(field.name), removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(s), field.nullable, field.metadata)
s.copy(name = replaceIllegal(field.name), dataType = removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(s))
```

---

There are some design patterns in functional languages (in general) and Scala (in particular) that could deal with the deep nested structure manipulation, but that might be too much (and I'm hesitant to share it).

I therefore think that the question is in its current "shape" more about how to manipulate a tree as a data structure not necessarily a Spark schema.

Comment: Thanks @Jacek - is there also no better way to apply the new schema?  I thought the code "df.select($"*".cast(removeIllegalCharsInColumnNames(df.schema)))" should work but using the * there is not allowed.  Is there no way to select the root of the DataFrame?

Comment: You could use `df.schema` to create a new schema (not `select("*"...`) Exactly what you want but a different way to do it.